# Will an Everstone prevent Tandemaus from evolving?

Tags: pokemon-scarlet-violet

Tandemous can randomly evolve into Maushold at level 25 or higher. There is no evolution animation or indication it has evolved until you check your party to see that one or two smaller mice have joined the couple.

Since there's no evolution screen for Tandemous, will an Everstone prevent it from evolving into a Maushold?

Comment: Can't test it right now, but the absence of the evolution screen shouldn't change its behaviour.